# How to select the same columns with different input

Tags: sql, reporting-services

The case is that I want to make a report using SSRS to compare the staff's Salary between 2 year.
The years, staff number and salary is in 1 table.

The table structure is is :
 `his_pay_period_num, his_employee_num, Salary`   for example:

[Salary]:

```
2007,A1234,$30000
2009,A1234,$50000
2009,B1234,$15000
```

I want to output:

```
A1234 , $30000, $50000   <-----how can I select 2 Salary with different input(2007,2009)?
B1234,  $0, $15000  <----------- And if no Record,return 0
```

Currently, I am doing:

```
SELECT  t1.his_pay_period_num, t1.his_employee_num ,t1.Salary AS rate1,
  t2.Salary AS rate2
FROM          [Salary] as t1 Left outer join
            [Salary] as t2 on t1.id = t2.id
WHERE        (t1.his_pay_period_num = '2007') or  (t2.his_pay_period_num= '2009')
```

It outputs:

```
A1234, $30000,$30000
A1234, $50000,$50000   <-----just display 2 record 
B1234, $15000,$15000
```

Problem 1 : How can I select 2 salaries with different input?

Problem 2 : And if no record exists, return 0

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your DBMS supports the `PIVOT` keyword, you can do something like this:

```
select 
his_employee_num, 
coalesce([2007],0) as [Pay in 2007], --0 if first argument is NULL
coalesce([2009],0) as [Pay in 2009]
from
(select * from salary) s
pivot
(max(salary) for his_pay_period in ([2007],[2009])) p
```

This will work on SQL Server and Oracle (possibly with a little tweaking needed).

Comment: first, thank you for your help,
I think i made a mistake or you misunderstand,

Comment: Please update YOUR QUESTION with the exact output you want to clarify further.

Comment: first, thank you for your help,my database is SQL SERVER 2008,
I think i made a mistake or you misunderstand,
the database [Salary]:has 3 columns,that is "his_pay_period", "his_employee_num", "Salary"
2007 and 2009 is the data for the "his_pay_period"
is the pivot also can use?

Comment: 2007 and 2009 become the column names when pivot is done. Did you try to run this query? Also I suggest you read up on pivot so you can see why 2007 and 2009 are hard coded here.

Comment: Sorry I make a mistake again, I am using the SSRS with SQL 2008 to make a report and the SSRS is not support the pivot